# Separate ports for app server and rest API server (Node)

Tags: node.js, rest, express

Are there any particular advantages/disadvantages to using separate ports for serving your app (rendering pages) and a rest API server? I'm working on building a React, Node/Express app and see examples in which the author has served the API on port 3030 and the app on port 3000. It seems that this would decouple the two, which is nice for testing. But are there otherwise *any distinct advantages of serving the app and the API on separate ports in a Node/Express application?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separating your API from your rendering server allows requests to be processed more efficiently by segregating your logic.

Express won't have to iterate through all the routes of your page rendering endpoints to reach the callback for an API request, and it won't have to iterate through all the routes of your API endpoints to reach the callback for a page rendering request.

Comment: My understanding is that Node/Express is event-driven (and super high performance as a result), so "iterating" over the routes is a non-issue...

Comment: @Himmel yes it is event-driven, meaning that every client request emits an event to the server listener. However, it needs to iterate through every `app.METHOD()` request to match the requested path to the request object and determine which callbacks to invoke. This is where the iteration happens.

Comment: Definitely. If this is the only reason, though, then it seems like it would *not* be worth separating the two if I only have one non-api route (`app.get()` that serves index.html).

Comment: @Himmel Then you are correct. In that case it wouldn't be worth your time, but you asked a general question, and I gave a general answer.

Comment: I did, and thank you for your response! Just wanted to follow up to make sure the way I'm thinking about it makes sense.